# Hosting certain pages on a different domain in an iframe produces weird results

Tags: asp.net, iframe, https

Folks,

I am working on an app that hosts certain pages from a different site in an iframe.  Because the site is on a different network, I get prompted to log into their network in order to show the pages.  All that is fine (the users of this site will be on the same network, so I'm not worrying about their logging in.)

However, on a different page, same app, I'm trying to do the same thing with a different set of pages from that same site.  This time, I don't get prompted to log in, but do get the DNS Error page in the iFrame (I'm doing this in IE9, if it matters.)  If I click "return to previous page" on the DNS Error page or right-click and click Back, the home page of the app (on the different network) appears in the iframe.  After that, trying to load the desired page in the iframe works.  But I'm baffled as to why and would prefer it load the first time I try it!

I'm guessing that the conjunction of the hosted pages being secure (HTTPS), their being on a different network, the iframe, and possibly also IE9 are somehow causing this.  Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks,

Ann L.

Comment: what happens if your try opening the page that has the error directly (not in the IFRAME)?

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "the site is on a different network"?

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT I probably misspoke.  The target page is on a different domain and I receive a Windows security login (for which I have to enter a user id and pwd) every time I open it in a new browser window.  This is true whether I'm physically plugged into the site owner's network or accessing the site from outside.

Comment: Turned out that while I was physically plugged into their network, my laptop belonged to a different domain.  Once that was changed, the problem went away.  Thanks, all of you who answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go directly to the url that the iframe is pointing at do you get that same error or does it work? And make sure you go to the page the iframe is looking at and not what you *think* it is looking at. It may be that at some point in your process the page is generating the wrong url for the iframe.

The other thing is that it may be worth using fiddler to check your traffic to see if these other pages are trying to do some kind of redirect on you - they may be checking referrer and not liking connections from outside their network or similar.

Comment: If I go to the page the iframe is looking at, I get a Windows security message prompting me to sign in.  I then get the desired page (in the browser window, not the iframe.)